# layout handle on shipment view admin not rendering the custom block

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, admin-panel

I am trying to add a block to be appear on shipment view. I successfully showing my custom block on sales order view, but I have to move it to shipment view. Here is what I want to achieve:

My custom block should be showing along with these blocks:
[image: sales shipment view]

My attempt:

```
<layout version="1.0">
   <adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
    <reference name="order_info">
        <block type="paketid_booking/adminhtml_sales_order_view_info_booking" name="paketid_booking.order.info.booking.block" template="paketid/booking.phtml" after="order_history" />
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
</layout>
```

My config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <PaketId_Booking>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </PaketId_Booking>
</modules>
<default>
    <paketid_booking>
        <api>
            <email>test@paket.id</email>
            <key>TEST-API-KEY</key>
            <debug>0</debug>
        </api>
    </paketid_booking>
  </default>
  <global>
     <blocks>
        <paketid_booking>
            <class>PaketId_Booking_Block</class>
        </paketid_booking>
     </blocks>
     <helpers>
        <paketid_booking>
            <class>PaketId_Booking_Helper</class>
        </paketid_booking>
     </helpers>

    <models>
        <paketid_booking>

            <class>PaketId_Booking_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>paketid_booking_resource</resourceModel>
        </paketid_booking>        

        <paketid_booking_resource>

            <class>PaketId_Booking_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <result>
                    <table>paketid_booking_result</table>
                </result>
            </entities>
        </paketid_booking_resource>

    </models>
    <resources>
        <paketid_booking_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>PaketId_Booking</module>
            </setup>
        </paketid_booking_setup>
    </resources>

    <events>
        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>

            <observers>

                <paketid_booking>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>PaketId_Booking_Model_Observer</class>

                    <method>processOrder</method>
                </paketid_booking>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    </events>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <paketid_booking>
                <file>paketid_booking.xml</file>
            </paketid_booking>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
            <observers>
                <paketid_booking>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                     <class>PaketId_Booking_Model_Adminhtml_Observer</class>
                    <method>getSalesOrderBookingInfo</method>
                </paketid_booking>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

`

My block structure:

[image]

I have not found any solution for this since yesterday, so you might have read this question and I am really sorry if I am breaking the rule. I need help

Answer (score 0):

try to change your layout file below and let me know its working or not

```
<layout version="1.0">
  <adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
      <reference name="content">
        <block type="paketid_booking/adminhtml_sales_order_view_info_booking" name="paketid_booking.order.info.booking.block" template="paketid/booking.phtml" after="order_history" />
     </reference>
   </adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
 </layout>
```

Comment: it's not working :( .. I wonder if it has something to do with my config or my folder structure?